# Javascript/jQuery adding an animation to replaceChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm fairly new to Javascript, so let me know if I'm doing something a little silly, but here's the gist:

I'm working with integrating a new feature into a very rigidly constructed template (I basically only get a single plaintext link). My workaround for this was to just add some jQuery that would add an onclick method that would replace the link with the element that I actually wanted to have.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a:contains('Search')").bind("click", replaceWithSearch);
});


function replaceWithSearch(){
    var searchWrapper = constructSearchBox("");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(searchWrapper, this);
}
```

That all works, but I've been talking with UI people over here and they want animations for this replacement. Of course their goto is to use CSS animations, but I'm not really sure how to add a smooth fade or slide animation to the replaceChild operation. Am I thinking about this the right way? If so how exactly would I add that animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS animations, you'd do something like the following:

```
.your-selector {
    animation: fadeIn 400ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/zt3QB/. That will make it start from 0 opacity when it is injected into the DOM, and go to the default, which is 1.

If you want to use jQuery:

```
function replaceWithSearch(){
    var searchWrapper = constructSearchBox("").css('opacity', 0);
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(searchWrapper, this);
    // Using setTimeout because sometimes the DOM is too fast...
    setTimeout(function() {
        searchWrapper.fadeTo(400, 1);
    }, 0);
}
```

I haven't tested the jQuery one, but I've done similar things. Just finished a project using the CSS version.

Comment: Oh, so I just add the css animation to the dom object that's being removed/inserted?

Comment: Yeah. I added a fiddle with the CSS animation example (and making up my own version of your `constructSearchBox` function).